# Off topic clarification

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) says:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

If I come up with **one** solution to a problem, but I don't like it or am unsure about it for some reason, is it considered off topic to ask for a better solution? Would it be more appropriate to put the code for the possibly bad solution on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

I would greatly appreciate some further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want people to analyze your solution, give it general critiques with limited guidance, then yes, it belongs on Code Review.  If you have very *specific* questions about the code, such as something like, "How much memory will this code use relative to this input value?" or "Will this function meet this requirement that it's output is always [...] given [...] as it's input, or are there cases I haven't properly handled?" then it could be ontopic on SO.  To post it on SO the question would need to have an answer that someone can prove is *the* answer.  That's not going to be the case for a question like, "Can this be improved?" or "Is there a better way of doing this?"

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. So "Is there a better way of doing this?" is clearly a Code Review question?

Comment: I disagree with your examples about being on-topic on SO. The first would be a simple "well, try it!" and the second does not have a definitive answer "did I handle all possible input scenarios? - How should we know? What's the input going to be?". Well, the second sounds like somebody should write UnitTests for that function, to be honest. Otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby The first would be a function of memory with respect to size of input, much as someone would measure execution time with respect to input size using Big O notation.  Does the program scale linearly with respect to problem size, polynomial, etc.?  As to the second, you most certainly can address (at least in certain circumstances) whether a particular function will work correctly for all possible input values.  You can only test a finite amount with unit testing.  I agree that this second one wouldn't be a *fantastic* question, but it would, if asked correctly, belong on SO.